# Scala/Spark: NoClassDefFoundError: net/liftweb/json/Formats

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, lift-json

I am trying to create a JSON String from a Scala Object as described [here](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/scala/9781449340292/15dot-web-services/ch15s02_html).

I have the following code:

```
import scala.collection.mutable._
import net.liftweb.json._
import net.liftweb.json.Serialization.write

case class Person(name: String, address: Address)
case class Address(city: String, state: String)

object LiftJsonTest extends App {

  val p = Person("Alvin Alexander", Address("Talkeetna", "AK"))

  // create a JSON string from the Person, then print it
  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
  val jsonString = write(p)
  println(jsonString)

}
```

My build.sbt file contains the following:

```
libraryDependencies += "net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % "2.5+"
```

When I build with `sbt package`, it is a success.

However, when I try to run it as a Spark job, like this:

```
spark-submit \
  --packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-pom:1.10.34,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.6.0,net.liftweb:lift-json:2.5+ \
  --class "com.foo.MyClass" \
  --master local[4] \
  target/scala-2.10/my-app_2.10-0.0.1.jar
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [unresolved dependency: net.liftweb#lift-json;2.5+: not found]
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitUtils$.resolveMavenCoordinates(SparkSubmit.scala:1068)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:154)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Is `net.liftweb:lift-json:2.5+` in my `packages` argument incorrect?  Do I need to add a resolver in build.sbt?

Answer (score 1):

> [Users may also include any other dependencies by supplying a comma-delimited list **of maven coordinates** with --packages.](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html)

`2.5+` in your `build.sbt` is [Ivy version matcher](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.1.0/settings/version-matchers.html) syntax, not actual artifact version needed for Maven coordinates. `spark-submit` apparently doesn't use Ivy for resolution (and I think it would be surprising if it did; your application could suddenly stop working because a new dependency version was published). So you need to find what version `2.5+` resolves to in your case e.g. using https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph (or trying to find it in `show dependencyClasspath`).

Comment: Best solution here is to use the latest release version of lift-json, which is 2.6.3.